Django Error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
Tengo un problema al actualizar los datos de registro en MySQL, en un proyecto Django. Lo que sucede es que al realizar el guardado de los datos en registro correspondiente me sale:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")

Ya revise el modelo que estoy utilizando:

CursosModel.py:

from django.db import models
from blog.Models.HistorialCambiosModel import HistorialCambios

class Cursos(models.Model):
    idcursos = models.IntegerField(db_column='idCursos', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nombre_curso = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre_Curso', max_length=120)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechainicial_curso = models.DateTimeField(db_column='FechaInicial_Curso')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechafina_cursol = models.DateTimeField(db_column='FechaFina_Cursol')  # Field name made lowercase.
    link_curso = models.CharField(db_column='Link_Curso', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    descripcion_cursol = models.CharField(db_column='Descripcion_Cursol', max_length=450)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'cursos'

Tambien revice el fomulario:

CursosForm.py:

from django.forms import ModelForm
from  blog.Models.CursosModel import Cursos

class CursosForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cursos
        fields = ['nombre_curso', 'fechainicial_curso', 'fechafina_cursol', 'link_curso', 'descripcion_cursol']

Y no se muy bien que puede ser de la vista (Update_cursos):

CursosAdmin.py:

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse
from blog.Models.CursosModel import Cursos
from blog.Forms.Cursosform import CursosForm
from blog.Views.decorators import login_required_with_token


@login_required_with_token
def cursos_admin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Entra al metodo post")
        print(request.POST)  
        form = CursosForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('cursos_admin')
    else:
        form = CursosForm()

    cursos = Cursos.objects.all()
    context = {
        'cursos': cursos,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/AdminCursos.html', context)

@login_required_with_token
def delete_curso(request, idcursos):
    curso = get_object_or_404(Cursos, idcursos=idcursos)
    curso.delete()
    return redirect('cursos_admin')

@login_required_with_token
def update_curso(request, idcursos):
    print("inicia el update")
    cursos = get_object_or_404(Cursos, idcursos=idcursos)
    print("Obtiene el objeto curso")
    print(cursos)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("Entra al metodo post")
        print(request.POST)  # Imprime los datos recibidos
        form = CursosForm(request.POST, instance=cursos)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("Guarda el curso")
            print(form.errors)
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'errors': form.errors})
    else:
        form = CursosForm(instance=cursos)
    return render(request, 'nombre_del_template.html', {'form': form})

Y vale aclarar que asi lo estoy llamando en el HTML:
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID Curso</th>
            <th>Nombre del curso</th>
            <th>Fecha de Inicio</th>
            <th>Fecha de Final</th>
            <th>Link del curso</th>
            <th>Descripción curso</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        {% for curso in cursos %}
        <tr id="row-{{ curso.idcursos }}">
            <td>{{ curso.idcursos }}</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nombre_curso" value="{{ curso.nombre_curso }}" class="form-control editable" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="fechainicial_curso" value="{{ curso.fechainicial_curso|date:"Y-m-d" }}" class="form-control editable" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="date" name="fechafina_cursol" value="{{ curso.fechafina_cursol|date:"Y-m-d" }}" class="form-control editable" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="link_curso" value="{{ curso.link_curso }}" class="form-control editable" readonly></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="descripcion_cursol" value="{{ curso.descripcion_cursol }}" class="form-control editable" readonly></td>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'delete_curso' curso.idcursos %}" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                <button class="btn btn-primary edit-btn"
                <button class="btn btn-primary edit-btn" data-id="{{ curso.idcursos }}">Editar</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success save-btn" data-id="{{ curso.idcursos }}" style="display:none;">Guardar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <script>
        function getCookie(name) {
            let cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Función para obtener el valor de una cookie
            $(document).on('click', '.edit-btn', function() {
                var idcursos = $(this).data('id');
                var row = $('#row-' + idcursos);
                row.find('.editable').prop('readonly', false);
                row.find('.edit-btn').hide();
                row.find('.save-btn').show();
            });
    
            $(document).on('click', '.save-btn', function() {
                var idcursos = $(this).data('id');
                var row = $('#row-' + idcursos);
    
                var data = {
                    nombre_curso: row.find('input[name="nombre_curso"]').val(),
                    fechainicial_curso: row.find('input[name="fechainicial_curso"]').val(),
                    fechafina_cursol: row.find('input[name="fechafina_cursol"]').val(),
                    link_curso: row.find('input[name="link_curso"]').val(),
                    descripcion_cursol: row.find('input[name="descripcion_cursol"]').val()
                };
    
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'update_curso' idcursos=0 %}".slice(0, -2) + idcursos + '/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status == 'success') {
                            row.find('.editable').prop('readonly', true);
                            row.find('.save-btn').hide();
                            row.find('.edit-btn').show();
                        } else if (response.status == 'error') {
                            alert('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(response.errors));
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

No se como solucionar este tipo de error con exactitud
